How do I send FCM requests to a large number of devices quickly?
I've inherited a Java project that sends push messages to various platforms, including Android an Chrome.
It also uses FCM legacy API, and we have to migrate it to FCM V1.
I've managed to deal with V1's APIs, everything seems to run smooth, except when it comes to big number of devices - theoretically, there could be a need to send push messages to 1M devices at a time, and I'm struggling to do it fast. In legacy API, it was done with batches of device tokens, but in V1, it can be only one token per request. Using topics is not feasible, because this project is built to have its own device grouping/segmentation.
I've tried sending requests in muptiple threads via ExecutorService with Futures, tried using http/2 client. Never reached acceptable results.
What would be the optimal path here? How do I send 1M requests to FCM in, say, 5 minutes?
threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(threadPoolExecutor);

final List<ListenableFuture<Result>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Recipient recipient : recipients) {
    final SettableFuture<Result> resultFuture = SettableFuture.create();
    ThreadPoolExecutor finalThreadPoolExecutor = threadPoolExecutor;
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        try {
            String pushToken = recipient.getPushToken();
            ListenableFuture<Result> sendFuture = sender.send(msg, pushToken);
            Futures.addCallback(sendFuture, new FutureCallback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Result input) {
                    Result result = new Result();
                    result.increaseRecipientsSent(new DeliveryResult(recipient));
                    resultFuture.set(result);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    Result value = ResultAnalyzer.analyzeV1Exception(recipient, t);
                    resultFuture.set(value);
                }
            }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resultFuture.set(ResultAnalyzer.analyzeException(Collections.singletonList(recipient), e));
        }
        return null;
    });
    futureList.add(resultFuture);
}

where sender.send is
public ListenableFuture<Result> sendNoRetry(Message message, String token) {
    String requestBody = createFcmV1Payload(message, token);
    ListenableFuture<HttpResponse> responseFuture = post(sendEndpoint, requestBody);
    return Futures.transformAsync(responseFuture, input -> {
        int status = input.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 503) {
            LOGGER.warn("FCM service is unavailable");
            return Futures.immediateFuture(null);
        }

        InputStream content = input.getEntity().getContent();
        processErrorResponse(status, content);
        return handleResponse(content);
    });
}

and post method just retrieves singleton http/2 client and sends the post request
client:
public class HttpClientManager {

    private static final HttpClientManager INSTANCE = new HttpClientManager();
    private final CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient;

    private HttpClientManager() {
        this.httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.customHttp2()
                .setIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig.custom()
                        .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofMinutes(1))
                        .setSelectInterval(Timeout.ofMilliseconds(100))
                        .build())
                .build();
        this.httpClient.start();
    }

    public static HttpClientManager getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public CloseableHttpAsyncClient getHttpClient() {
        return httpClient;
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        httpClient.close();
    }
}

StackOverflow says I need to add debugging details, but there are none. Please advise on how to send 1m requests to FCM in very short time frame. Help me with strategy, and I will sort out the tactics. Thank you

You can use Send messages to device groups (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group) . The maximum number of members allowed for a notification key is 20.

sending to 1m recipients via groups means sending at least 50k requests to create groups, then 50k requests to send messages to those. it decreases the amount of requests by 10 times, yes, but sending 100k requests instead of 1m is still nowhere near the time limit.
also, we're expecting delivery results per each device. sending to groups returns (almost) nothing in response

Check out this HTTP/2 multiplexing Java implementation by Emin Deniz which may help: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/834#issuecomment-2107964352
